In SwiftUI, when using HStack, why does it result in a vertical layout instead of a horizontal layout?
I'm new to SwiftUI. I know the hstack is the horizontal layout , but why it show vertical in this case ?
 @SceneBuilder
    private func menuBarExtra() -> some Scene {
        
        if #available(macOS 13.0, *)  {

            MenuBarExtra(isInserted: $statusMenu){
                AppMenu()
            } label: {
                let image: NSImage = {
                    let ratio = $0.size.height / $0.size.width
                    $0.size.height = 18
                    $0.size.width = 18 / ratio
                    return $0
                }(NSImage(named: "Finder")!)
                
                Image(nsImage: image)
            }
        }
        

   struct AppMenu: View {
    
      var body: some View {
         HStack{
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
                Text("3")
            }
       }
    }

Macos Menu bar application :
enter image description here
How can i customize layout in  MenuBarExtra ?
How can i customize layout in  MenuBarExtra ?

try giving your HStack a frame width, eg .frame(width: 123)

This is because the default menu bar extra style displays your views in a menu, and menus don't support displaying every type of view.
Menus don't respects layouts like HStack, ZStack. There is only one way that things in a menu can be laid out - vertically.
The .window style supports many more types of views, because instead of displaying a menu, it puts your views inside a window. You can switch to that style:
MenuBarExtra(isInserted: $statusMenu) {
    // ...
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

But of course you would lose the look-and-feel of a menu.
Incidentally, a ControlGroup in a menu would create a submenu, with that submenu's title being a concatenation of the textual elements in the ControlGroup. This looks similar to a horizontal layout. (but it technically isn't)
ControlGroup {
    Text("Foo")
    Text("Bar")
    Text("Baz")
}



There are two styles in MenuBarExtra

menu – the default style – which is a more easy to use but more restricted menu like the menu of NSStatusItem. You can only show menus (like NSMenu) and menu items (like NSMenuItem). Anything else is ignored. Unlike NSStatusItem you cannot attach custom views to the menu items nor to the status item button.

window which is a standard window without a title bar. You can do in the window almost anything you like.


In both styles you can show an animated and styled SFSymbol along with a (non-attributed) string in the menu bar.

The vertical alignment is the default behavior of the MenuBarExtra. To have the items horizontally aligned you need to change that style.
MenuBarExtra(currentNumber, systemImage: "triangle") {
            HStack{
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
                Text("3")
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

